# Data.table and get() command (R)

Tags: r, function, data.table

I have a problem including a `data.table` operation in a function. Input arguments are the data.table name and the column/variable name.

I can refer to the data.table by using the `get()` command. However, using the same command for the variable name doesn't work out. I know that `get()` might not be appropriate in case of the column/variable name, but I am stuck with which command to use.

**EDITED:** I have now included `substitute()` instead of `get()` and it still doesn't work.

```
toy_example_fun <- function(d, .expr){

  .expr = substitute(.expr)

  setkey(get(d), .expr)  # ==> doesn't work

  d.agg <- get(d)[,list(sum(y), sum(v)), by=.expr]  # --> works
}

toy_example_fun("DT", x)
```

**ALTERNATIVE:** `quote()` --> This works. However, I am interested in a solution that works inside a function.

```
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)    
d <- "DT"
variable <- quote(x)
d.agg <- get(d)[,list(sum(y), sum(v)), by=variable]
```

Even though, the latter alternative works `variable <- quote(x)` produces an error message:

```
  <simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'x' not found>
    <simpleError in is.scalar(val): object 'x' not found>
    <simpleError in is.data.frame(obj): object 'x' not found>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using data.table i and j arguments in functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705488/using-data-table-i-and-j-arguments-in-functions)

Comment: Thanks for referring me to your thread, Andrie. However, somehow it still won't work if I use `substitute()`.

Comment: Please edit your question by incorporating the suggestions in the answer to the linked question - otherwise you risk it getting closed as a duplicate.

Comment: This is still a duplicate. You should use `quote(x)` as explained in the linked answer.

Comment: @Andrie Nice pointer to other question. Strictly not a duplicate because OP seems to want function that accepts character inputs. If all OP wants is to pass column names around to group by (and not language expressions) then just passing character column names to by can be simpler. As usual, many ways to skin the cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
someFun <- function(d, .expr){
  group <- substitute(.expr)
  get(d)[,list(sum(y), sum(v)), by=group]
}

someFun("DT", x)
   group V1 V2
1:     a 10  6
2:     b 10 15
3:     c 10 24


someFun("DT", "x")
   x V1 V2
1: a 10  6
2: b 10 15
3: c 10 24
```

---

EDIT from Matthew :

+1 to above. And/Or character column names are acceptable to `by` directly, too :

```
someFun = function(d, col) {
    get(d)[,list(sum(y),sum(v)),by=col]
}
someFun("DT","x")
   x V1 V2
1: a 10  6
2: b 10 15
3: c 10 24
someFun("DT","x,y")
   x y V1 V2
1: a 1  1  1
2: a 3  3  2
3: a 6  6  3
4: b 1  1  4
5: b 3  3  5
6: b 6  6  6
7: c 1  1  7
8: c 3  3  8
9: c 6  6  9
```

but then `someFun("DT",x)` won't work. So Adrie's answer is more general.

---

EDIT with `setkeyv`

```
someFun <- function(d, cols){
  setkeyv(get(d), cols)
  cols <- substitute(cols)
  get(d)[,list(sum(y), sum(v)), by=cols]
}

someFun("DT", "x")
   x V1 V2
1: a 10  6
2: b 10 15
3: c 10 24
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrie and Matthew. Your answers helped me a lot. However, in my final function I also need to use the `setkey()` command. While the other part works, the line `setkey(get(d), .expr)` still doesn't work. Actually, that was the reason for my confusion (I never had a look at the aggregation as I have gotten the error from `setkey()` in the first place.)

Comment: @majom Try `?setkeyv` instead (extra v on the end).

Comment: Done. Thanks for the hint and thanks for developing such an awesome package!