# r data.table usage in function call

Tags: r, encoding, data.table, categorical-data, binning

I want to perform a data.table task over and over in a function call: [Reduce number of levels for large categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066382/reduce-number-of-levels-for-large-categorical-variables?noredirect=1#comment65482577_39066382) My problem is similar to [Data.table and get() command (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859063/data-table-and-get-command-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [pass column name in data.table using variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable-in-r) but I can't get it to work

Without a function call this works just fine:

```
# Load data.table
require(data.table)

# Some data
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(type = factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 10e3, replace = T)),
                 weight = rnorm(n = 10e3, mean = 70, sd = 20))

# Decide the minimum frequency a level needs...
min.freq <- 3350

# Levels that don't meet minumum frequency (using data.table)
fail.min.f <- dt[, .N, type][N < min.freq, type]

# Call all these level "Other"
levels(dt$type)[fail.min.f] <- "Other"
```

but wrapped like

```
reduceCategorical <- function(variableName, min.freq){
  fail.min.f <- dt[, .N, variableName][N < min.freq, variableName]
  levels(dt[, variableName][fail.min.f]) <- "Other"
}
```

I only get errors like:

```
 reduceCategorical(dt$x, 3350)
Fehler in levels(df[, variableName][fail.min.f]) <- "Other" : 
 trying to set attribute of NULL value
```

And sometimes

```
Error is: number of levels differs
```

Comment: It is always better to use a `data.table` syntax when working with `data.table`....

Comment: What are you referring to? `df[, variableName][fail.min.f]` is correct data.table isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not correct way to work with factors. You could do this in two steps, but I haven't tested for efficiency: `dt[type %in% fail.min.f, type := "Other"]; dt[, type := factor(type)]` I'll try to think of a better way though

Comment: Strange - your method is setting all values in the type column to Other.

Comment: No it's not.... Btw, your function doesn't have a `df` variable and you should be aware that `:=` modifies data.tables within functions too

Comment: thanks - edited it.

Comment: In single use case, your solution works just fine. But within the function everything is marked as Other.

Comment: `f <- function(var, min.freq) {fail.min.f <- dt[, .N, by = var][N < min.freq, get(var)];dt[get(var) %in% fail.min.f, (var) := "Other"];dt[, (var) := factor(get(var))]};f("type", min.freq)`

Comment: Another version of the same function `f <- function(var, min.freq) {fail.min.f <- dt[, .I[.N < min.freq], by = var]$V1;set(dt, fail.min.f, var, "other");set(dt, NULL, var, factor(dt[[var]]))}`

Comment: Thanks a lot - that works. Which one of the two would you recommend?

Comment: The second one. But there must be a better way

Comment: Try also `f <- function(variableName, min.freq){fail.min.f <- dt[, .N, by = variableName][N < min.freq, get(variableName)];invisible(dt[, setattr(get(variableName), "levels", c(setdiff(levels(get(variableName)), fail.min.f), rep("other", length(fail.min.f))))])}` - it seems like the best option to me

Comment: Why does the last variant only work if everything is in a single line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You could break it to lined where `;` is and remove it

Comment: Indeed that's what I tried but then everything was labelled as "other"

Comment: It modifies everything in place. Once you run it once, your data set will be already modified *in place*. The second time you'll run it, it will be already on the previously modified data set. If you don't want to modify in place just use the base R syntax: `f <- function(df, variableName, min.freq){fail.min.f <- df[, .N, by = variableName][N < min.freq, get(variableName)];levels(df$type)[fail.min.f] <- "Other";df} ;f(dt, "type", min.freq)`. This will leave your original `dt` unmodified and return a whole new data set

Comment: ok - so there must have been an issue on my side

Comment: @DAvid do you want to write your last function as "the solution" ?

Comment: Why, you like the base R solution best? So why do you need the `data.table` package here in the first place :)

Comment: sorry - I did mean the one from 19 mins ago with data.table ;) But choose the one you see fit. I will go with the data.table version.

Comment: Btw, do you insist on `factors`? You could do the whole process in a single simple line if `type` were a `character`. Something like `dt[, type := as.character(type)] ; dt[, type := if(.N < min.freq) "other", by = type]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121542/discussion-between-geoheil-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to define your own re-leveling function using `data.table::setattr` that will modify `dt` in place. Something like

```
DTsetlvls <- function(x, newl)  
   setattr(x, "levels", c(setdiff(levels(x), newl), rep("other", length(newl))))
```

Then use it within another predefined function

```
f <- function(variableName, min.freq){
  fail.min.f <- dt[, .N, by = variableName][N < min.freq, get(variableName)]
  dt[, DTsetlvls(get(variableName), fail.min.f)]
  invisible()
}

f("type", min.freq)
levels(dt$type)
# [1] "C"     "other"
```

---

Some other `data.table` alternatives

```
f <- function(var, min.freq) {
  fail.min.f <- dt[, .N, by = var][N < min.freq, get(var)]
  dt[get(var) %in% fail.min.f, (var) := "Other"]
  dt[, (var) := factor(get(var))]
}
```

Or using `set`/`.I`

```
f <- function(var, min.freq) {
  fail.min.f <- dt[, .I[.N < min.freq], by = var]$V1
  set(dt, fail.min.f, var, "other")
  set(dt, NULL, var, factor(dt[[var]]))
}
```

Or combining with base R (doesn't modify original data set)

```
f <- function(df, variableName, min.freq){
  fail.min.f <- df[, .N, by = variableName][N < min.freq, get(variableName)]
  levels(df$type)[fail.min.f] <- "Other"
  df
}
```

Alternatively, we could stick we `character`s instead (if `type` is a `character`), you could simply do

```
f <- function(var, min.freq) dt[, (var) := if(.N < min.freq) "other", by = var]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing things little differently in the wrapper, to get "type" column name you are using the whole `variableName` which is actually a vector  same with getting levels, you are not using `variableName` directly as done in function

The error is because value of `fail.min.f` is coming NULL owing to referencing.

Comment: I used dt$x e.g. the whole name in order to prevent the error of using `reduceCategorical('x', 3350)` which results in the following error: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , variableName, value = c("x", NA)) :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'x' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).

Comment: In case `fail.min.f` is the last statement - it is not null and prints the desired result.