# How to use data.table inside a function?

Tags: r, data.table

As a minimal working example, for instance, I want to be able to dynamically pass expressions to a data.table object to create new columns or modify existing ones:

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1, y = 2)
dynamicDT <- function(...) {
    dt[, list(...)]
}
dynamicDT(z = x + y)
```

I was expecting:

```
   z
1: 3
```

but instead, I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

So how can I fix this?

### Attempts:

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705488/using-data-table-i-and-j-arguments-in-functions), which suggests using `quote` or `substitute`, but

```
> dynamicDT(z = quote(x + y))
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(format(rn, right = TRUE),  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

or

```
> dynamicDT <- function(...) {
+     dt[, list(substitute(...))]
+ }
> dynamicDT(z = x + y)
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  first argument must be atomic
```

haven't worked for me.

Comment: You won't get that desired output if you will use `list`. If you function will work, the output will be `z 1: 3`. You need to use `:=`

Comment: @DavidArenburg. Thanks for pointing that out - was an oversight when writing. Fixed now.

Comment: I actually wrote an answer for your original desired output, do you still need it

Comment: Sure - thanks David. Shouldn't be too hard to tweak the final output. The important bit is how you manage to pass expressions to be evaluated in context of the data.table rather than `.GlobalEnv`.

Comment: See my edit re multiple variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be a better alternative to David's answer:

```
dynamicDT <- function(...) {
 dt[, eval(substitute(...))]
}

dynamicDT(z := x + y)
#   x y z
#1: 1 2 3
```

Comment: (+1) Nice one @Roland, certainly better

Comment: Thanks - can this handle multiple arguments such as `dynamicDT(a := x + y, b := x - y)`?

Comment: It still has to be correct data.table syntax. See David's answer for the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `eval(parse(text = ))` combination. `parse` will transform the string into an expression, while `eval` will evaluate it.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1, y = 2)
dynamicDT <- function(temp = "") {
  dt[, eval(parse(text = temp))]
}
```

In order to get your previous desired output

```
dynamicDT("z := x + y")
##    x y z
## 1: 1 2 3
```

In order to get your current desired output

```
dynamicDT("z = x + y")
## [1] 3
```

In order to parse multiple arguments you can do

`dynamicDT('c("a","b") := list(x + y, x - y)')`

```
##   x y a  b
##1: 1 2 3 -1
```