# How to use non-standard evaluation NSE to evaluate arguments on data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, nse

Say I have the following

```r
library(data.table)
cars1 = setDT(copy(cars))
cars2 = setDT(copy(cars))

car_list = list(cars1, cars2)
class(car_list) <- "dd"

`[.dd` <- function(x,...) {
  code = rlang::enquos(...)
  cars1 = x[[1]]
  rlang::eval_tidy(quo(cars1[!!!code]))
}

car_list[,.N, by = speed]
```

so I wished to perform arbitrary operations on `cars1` and `cars2` by defining the `[.dd` function so that whatever I put into `...` get executed by `cars1` and `cars2` using the `[` data.table syntax e.g.

`car_list[,.N, by = speed]` should perform the following

```r
cars1[,.N, by = speed]
cars2[,.N, by = speed]
```

also I want

```r
car_list[,speed*2]
```

to do

```r
cars1[,speed*2]
cars2[,speed*2]
```

Basically, `...` in `[.dd` has to accept arbitrary code.

somehow I need to capture the `...` so I tried to do `code = rlang::enquos(...)` and then `rlang::eval_tidy(quo(cars1[!!!code]))` doesn't work and gives error

> Error in `[.data.table`(cars1, ~, ~.N, by = ~speed) : 
>         argument "i" is missing, with no default

Comment: I don't use rlang but the tildes in the error message shouldn't be there. data.table subsetting doesn't expect formulas.

Comment: @Roland I don't need to use rlang if I don't have to, but i just don't know how to achieve what I want. Hence the question

Comment: I'd just use base eval after substituting the expression into the subset expression ( with base functionality).

Comment: @Roland I would accept the answer if you just post an example as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Maybe later this weekend if someone else doesn't do it. No R on my phone.

Comment: Try using `rlang::enexprs` instead of `enquos`, and remove the call to `quo` inside `eval_tidy`, it's not needed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you *can’t* use tidyeval here, because tidyeval needs to be supported by the callee, and the data.table subsetting operator doesn’t support tidyeval. As a consequence, this is unfortunately a lot more complicated to achieve.

Comment: related qn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705488/using-data-table-i-and-j-arguments-in-functions

Comment: Is there a reason why you would like to do this? Just curious

Comment: @marble it's for my package disk.frame https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First base R option is `substitute(...())` followed by `do.call`:

```
library(data.table)
cars1 = setDT(copy(cars))
cars2 = setDT(copy(cars))
cars2[, speed := sort(speed, decreasing = TRUE)]

car_list = list(cars1, cars2)
class(car_list) <- "dd"

`[.dd` <- function(x,...) {
  a <- substitute(...()) #this is an alist
  expr <- quote(x[[i]])
  expr <- c(expr, a)
  res <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    res[[i]] <- do.call(data.table:::`[.data.table`, expr)
  }
  res
}

all.equal(
  car_list[,.N, by = speed],
  list(cars1[,.N, by = speed], cars2[,.N, by = speed])
)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(
  car_list[, speed*2],
  list(cars1[, speed*2], cars2[, speed*2])
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Second base R option is `match.call`, modify the call and then evaluate (you find this approach in `lm`):

```
`[.dd` <- function(x,...) {
  thecall <- match.call()
  thecall[[1]] <- quote(`[`)
  thecall[[2]] <- quote(x[[i]])
  res <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    res[[i]] <- eval(thecall)
  }
  res
}

all.equal(
  car_list[,.N, by = speed],
  list(cars1[,.N, by = speed], cars2[,.N, by = speed])
)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(
  car_list[, speed*2],
  list(cars1[, speed*2], cars2[, speed*2])
)
#[1] TRUE
```

I haven't tested if these approaches will make a deep copy if you use `:=`.

Comment: may i ask what is `...()`.i looked thr R internals and R lang defn and found only `...` dot-dot-dot arguments

Comment: I learned this on the R-devel mailing list. You can use `substitute` to create a call like this `foo <- function(x) {substitute(x())}; foo(bar)`. Now, instead of `x` we substitute `...`. I don't know exactly why we then don't get a call object , but a call is a pairlist internally and that's what we get. If you want something easier to understand, use what Hadley suggests in his book: `eval(substitute(alist(...)))`

Comment: thanks. found by trial and error that `quote(...)` works as well. will read up more on nse

Comment: can handle car_list[, abc := speed*3] where as @Alexis's can't. Hence the solution!

Comment: Is there a way to no use :::? As CRAN won't accept it. Actually, changing to `[` also works!

Comment: The first approach also works with just `\`[\`` (as does the second approach).

Answer (score 5):

While not under `rlang` type of mantra, this approach seems to work pretty well: `lapply(dt_list, '[', ...)` The code would be more readable to me as it is explicit about what method is being used. If I saw `car_list[, .N, by = speed]` I would expect the default `data.table` methods.

Making it as a function allows you to have the best of both worlds:

```
class(car_list) <- "dd"

`[.dd` <- function(x,...) {
 lapply(x, '[', ...)
}

car_list[, .N, speed]
car_list[, speed * 2]
car_list[, .(.N, max(dist)), speed]
car_list[, `:=` (more_speed = speed+5)]
```

Here are some examples of the approach:

```
car_list[, .N, speed]
# lapply(car_list, '[', j = .N, by = speed)
# or
# lapply(car_list, '[', , .N, speed)
[[1]]
    speed N
 1:     4 2
 2:     7 2
 3:     8 1
 4:     9 1
 5:    10 3
...
[[2]]
    speed N
 1:     4 2
 2:     7 2
 3:     8 1
 4:     9 1
 5:    10 3
...
car_list[, speed * 2]
# lapply(car_list, '[', j = speed*2)
# or
# lapply(car_list, '[', , speed*2)
[[1]]
 [1]  8  8 14 14 16 18 20 20 20 22 22 24 24 24 24 26 26
[18] 26 26 28 28 28 28 30 30 30 32 32 34 34 34 36 36 36
[35] 36 38 38 38 40 40 40 40 40 44 46 48 48 48 48 50

[[2]]
 [1]  8  8 14 14 16 18 20 20 20 22 22 24 24 24 24 26 26
[18] 26 26 28 28 28 28 30 30 30 32 32 34 34 34 36 36 36
[35] 36 38 38 38 40 40 40 40 40 44 46 48 48 48 48 50

car_list[, .(.N, max(dist)), speed]
# lapply(car_list, '[', j = list(.N, max(dist)), by = speed)
# or 
# lapply(car_list, '[', ,.(.N, max(dist)), speed)

[[1]]
    speed N  V2
 1:     4 2  10
 2:     7 2  22
 3:     8 1  16
 4:     9 1  10
 5:    10 3  34
...

[[2]]
    speed N  V2
 1:     4 2  10
 2:     7 2  22
 3:     8 1  16
 4:     9 1  10
 5:    10 3  34
...
```

This works with the `:=` operator:

```
car_list[, `:=` (more_speed = speed+5)]
# or
# lapply(car_list, '[', , `:=` (more_speed = speed+5))

car_list
[[1]]
    speed dist more_speed
 1:     4    2          9
 2:     4   10          9
 3:     7    4         12
 4:     7   22         12
 5:     8   16         13
...

[[2]]
    speed dist more_speed
 1:     4    2          9
 2:     4   10          9
 3:     7    4         12
 4:     7   22         12
 5:     8   16         13
```

Comment: It's sort of missing the point. It's not for me, it's for the end user, so I need it to be callable like this dt_list[...].

Comment: See edit which is more or less ```[.dd <- function(x, ...) { lapply(x, '[', ...)}``` works as well. Although I can't comment the code in this box that well. P.S. I agree, I thought I would get downvoted originally for not really answering the question :)

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion in my comment wasn't complete.
You can indeed use `rlang` to support tidy evaluation,
but since `data.table` itself doesn't support it directly,
you're better off using expressions instead of quosures,
and you need to build the complete final expression before calling `eval_tidy`:

```
`[.dd` <- function(x, ...) {
  code <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  lapply(x, function(dt) {
    ex <- rlang::expr(dt[!!!code])
    rlang::eval_tidy(ex)
  })
}

car_list[, .N, by = speed]
[[1]]
    speed N
 1:     4 2
 2:     7 2
 3:     8 1
 4:     9 1
 5:    10 3
 6:    11 2
 7:    12 4
 8:    13 4
 9:    14 4
10:    15 3
11:    16 2
12:    17 3
13:    18 4
14:    19 3
15:    20 5
16:    22 1
17:    23 1
18:    24 4
19:    25 1

[[2]]
    speed N
 1:     4 2
 2:     7 2
 3:     8 1
 4:     9 1
 5:    10 3
 6:    11 2
 7:    12 4
 8:    13 4
 9:    14 4
10:    15 3
11:    16 2
12:    17 3
13:    18 4
14:    19 3
15:    20 5
16:    22 1
17:    23 1
18:    24 4
19:    25 1
```

Comment: It's a great solution, but it couldn't handle `car_list[, abc := speed*3]`.

Comment: @xiaodai If you want to use `:=`, you'd need to pass `.unquote_names = FALSE` to `enexprs`. `rlang` also uses `:=` for its own purposes, so interaction between it and `data.table` requires special considerations.